# Picking three random coins. Probability of them being the same and different material

Tags: probability, probability-theory

You are given $6$ gold coins, $4$ silver coins, and $3$ bronze coins. You pick three coins at random. What is the probability that t$hey are all of different material? What is the probability that are all of the same material?

The first part is easy since you can do 
$$
\frac{6}{13}\cdot \frac{4}{12} \cdot \frac{3}{11} = \frac{6}{143}.
$$

The second part is the one I am having trouble with. I know the probability of picking of picking only gold coins is $\frac{6}{13}\cdot\frac{5}{12}\cdot\frac{4}{11}$. I can do the same for silver and bronze. does this problem have to do rather with combinations, where I find the number of combinations that result in all gold, all silver, and all bronze. And then divide that by $13\cdot12\cdot11$?

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: I have some doubt about your answer to the "easy" first part. Suppose you only had 1 gold coin, 1 silver coin, and 1 bronze coin, and you pick 3 coins at random; what's the probability they are all of different material? Is it 1/3*1/2*1/1 = 1/6? That doesn't sound right, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combinatorial approach and assume that order doesn't matter. Then for the first question, we obtain:
$$
\frac{\binom{6}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}}{\binom{13}{3}}
= \frac{6 \cdot 4 \cdot 3}{\frac{13 \cdot 12 \cdot 11}{3 \cdot 2}}
= \frac{6 \cdot 4 \cdot 3}{13 \cdot 2 \cdot 11}
= \frac{36}{143}
$$
As bof pointed out in the comments, your answer was off by a factor of $3! = 6$, since you implicitly assumed a particular order of the $3$ types of coins.

For the second question, we consider all $3$ of each type of coin as separate cases (which was exactly what you were thinking of doing). This yields:
$$
\frac{\binom{6}{3} + \binom{4}{3} + \binom{3}{3}}{\binom{13}{3}}
= \frac{\frac{6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4}{3 \cdot 2} + 4 + 1}{\frac{13 \cdot 12 \cdot 11}{3 \cdot 2}}
= \frac{5 \cdot 4 + 5}{13 \cdot 2 \cdot 11}
= \frac{25}{286}
$$